QuickTime with alpha renders choppy
I’m using the latest version of Blender with an Apple MacBook Pro M3 Pro.
When I render an animation with any other setting it’s fine, but if I export as a QuickTime with an alpha channel then the video is choppy. This is true whether I run the file through Final Cut Pro or use the  “view animation” in Blender.
I think it has do with the encoding but I don't know enough to troubleshoot.  Any insights would be helpful. I'm just trying to get a video with an alpha channel. Thanks!

I have the same issue. plz. somebody help.
